# Tensorflow 1.14: InvalidArgumentError: device CUDA:0 not supported by XLA service while setting up XLA_GPU_JIT device number 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow 1.14 with 2 GPUs, but both of them are occupied by another colleague for 20 days. Is there a way to run my code on the CPU? I have tried

```
config123 = tf.ConfigProto(device_count = {'GPU': 0})
with tf.Session(config=config123) as sess:
```

and

`os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'`

but they still give the error mentioned in the title. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ```os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '' ```  works on Tensorflow 1.14 with CUDA 1.11

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a particular operation to run on a device of your choice instead of what's automatically selected for you, you can use with `tf.device` to create a device context, and all the operations within that context will run on the same designated device.

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```